# Matching Two List values and finally get a final List with distinct value

Tags: java, list, iterator, arraylist

I have question here. I have two list and both this list have some common elements.
This common elements along with the values has to be put in another List. which is very annoying as is the requirement.

My Testing Classes are as:

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

public class Player {
    private int singleModeVal;
    private int doubleModeVal;
    private String mode;
    private String name;
    public Player(){}

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getSingleModeVal(){
        return singleModeVal;

    }
    public void setSingleModeVal(int val1){
        this.singleModeVal=val1;
    }
    public int getDoubleModeVal(){
        return doubleModeVal;
    }
    public void setDoubleModeVal(int val2){
        this.doubleModeVal=val2;
    }
    public String getMode(){
        return mode;
    }
    public void setMode(String mode){
        this.mode = mode;
    }
    public List<Player> getSinglePlayerscoreList(){
        List<Player> singlePlayerscoreList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setName("A");
            player.setMode("singlePlayerMode");
            player.setSingleModeVal(100);
            player.setDoubleModeVal(200);
            singlePlayerscoreList.add(player);
        }
        return singlePlayerscoreList;
    }
    public List<Player> getDoublePlayerscoreList(){
        List<Player> doublePlayerscoreList = new ArrayList<Player>();
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
            Player player = new Player();
            player.setName("B");
            player.setMode("doublePlayerMode");
            player.setSingleModeVal(300);
            player.setDoubleModeVal(400);
            doublePlayerscoreList.add(player);
        }
        return doublePlayerscoreList;
    }
}
```

The Other class is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Tester {
    private Player player = new Player();

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Tester().showValue();
    }

    private void showValue(){
        List<Player> singlePlayerScore = new ArrayList<Player>();
        List<Player> doublePlayerScore = new ArrayList<Player>();
        singlePlayerScore = player.getSinglePlayerscoreList();
        doublePlayerScore = player.getDoublePlayerscoreList();
        List<Player> allScoreList = new  ArrayList<Player>();
        allScoreList.addAll(singlePlayerScore);
        allScoreList.addAll(doublePlayerScore);
            How do i iterate here, and print my data as:


 Name         singlePlayerScore  Double Player Score  TotalScore     
 A              100                   200                300     
 B              300                   400                700


     }
    }

}
```

When i iterate i get A twice with its value and B as same.

Is there an efficient way to perform as required.

Comment: Why do you iterate the for loop in getSinglePlayerscoreList and getDoublePlayerscoreList twice? That's at least why you get A and B twice in the iteration in showValue.

Comment: Your `Player` class needs both `equals()` and `hashCode()` -- you can't really work with the Collection API without these methods. Then check out [`List.retainAll()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Player implementing Comparable<Player>, would enable: Set<Player> list = new TreeSet<Player>();

Comment: @DavidBurstrom the for loop was intentional because that;s where rs.next() does in my case.

Answer (score 1):

There is method named `retainAll()` that does exactly opposite action.

So, you can do the following:

```
// create copies of source list because retainAll() works in place
List<T> copy1 = new ArrayList<T>(one);
List<T> copy2 = new ArrayList<T>(two);
copy1.retainAll(two);
copy2.retainAll(one);
// now copy1 and copy2 contain common elements

// create collection of retained elements
List<T> retained = new ArrayList<T>();
retained.addAll(copy1);
retained.addAll(copy2);

// refresh content of copy1 and copy2 (it is abuse but ok for the example)
copy1 = new ArrayList<T>(one);
copy2 = new ArrayList<T>(two);
// remove all retained elements, so now both collection contain elements unique for these collections only
copy1.removeAll(retained);
copy2.removeAll(retained);

// create collection that contains all distinct elements.
List<T> distinct = new ArrayList<T>();

distinct.addAll(copy1);
distinct.addAll(copy2);
```